# How can a superclass implement method of an interface "via a subclass"

Tags: java, class

```
public class EReader {
    public void turnPage(){
        System.out.println("E-Reader version used");
    }
}

public class Kindle extends EReader implements Book{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Kindle k = new Kindle();
        k.turnPage();
    }
}

interface Book{
    void turnPage();
}
```

I was reading about the deadly diamond of death in languages where you can inherit from more than one superclass. Java avoids this by using interfaces. I was curious about which method a class will call if that method is present in both its superclass and interface. So I wrote up this test code. I was using IntelliJ Idea for this and a tool tip next to the method in superclass (EReader) said *implements method in Book via subclass Kindle*.

I do not get how the method from an interface is implemented in a class which does not actually *implement* the interface. Is this just because the subclass implements the interface, therefore the superclass gets to implement the interface methods.

Sorry for my poor wording, I'll try to explain better if you need me to. Cheers!

Comment: `EReader` does not strictly implement `Book` but **IntelliJ** can still know that the subclass implements it and therefore **gives you a hint**. This is simply an IntelliJ feature, in terms of pure java "implements method in Book via subclass Kindle" does not "exist".

Comment: @luk2302 but how does the subclass implement it? I have no method in the subclass which actually overrides the interface method. I am just calling a method which happens to have the same name from my superclass. Its that class (i.e EReader) which actually implements this interface method or am I still very wrong

Comment: Of course you have, `Kindle` has `turnPage` from its parent and therefore conforms to the interface. No, `EReader` does not implement the interface because there is no `implements ...` there, it *could* implement the interface but it does not.

Comment: @luk2302 that makes sense! Even if I dont call the turnPage() method I still inherit it from my superclass thus fulfilling my contract to the interface by implementing that method. Thanks a million! If you could post your comments as an answer I could mark it answered.